# Linking values between inputs or so

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So my first explanation was difficult to read nad It was'nt fully correct as well. I'll try to explain it again. I have a strongly typed view where you enter a number. This view also has several strongly typed partial-views created in a for-loop. Each partial view is strongly typed and the model-item of each partial has a "Number"-property. The value of this property should be the entered number of the "parent"-view. How do I link the value of the entered number with the number property of the partial view model elements.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please consider formatting your question a little better, maybe giving some sample code that you've tried already.  At the moment just understanding what you're asking is hard work

Comment: Hi, sorry I know it's hard to understand but posting sample code would make it worst. THis is only part of a very complex thing and it would be more confusing if I post the code. I edited the question and I hope it is a bit clearer now.

Comment: Are you wanting to change the number on the client side?

Comment: Serer side would be better. Is there any way to tell mvc to set the value of a hidden field depending on the value of an other field?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be creating a property on `B` to hold the number of `A`. You could have have `B` reference an instance of `A`.

The view model should encapsulate all of the data needed for the view (or partial view) to render, it sounds like this includes the "property number" of `A` on a `B` object.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunatly I just recognized that there is an error in my explanation. There actually is no object A. It's just a single Input-field and the Value of this field should be referenced to the number property of every single B element.

Answer (score 0):

IF I understand your question correctly, you should simply be able to pass the value of the number (integer or decimal) as the Model parameter to the Partial View Call.

Regardless of whether you are returning a partial or calling a render partial, you can pass the model value in.

So

```
@Html.RenderPartial("ViewName",Model.WhateverTheNumberIsCalledInYourParentModel)
```